# Accessing variable outside function

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope

I have a javascript code with functions:

```
function convertTime()
function loadZive()
```

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
function convertTime(){
    alert(exampleVariable);
    };
function loadZive(){
    var exampleVariable = 3;
    convertTime();
    };
```

It looks like my `convertTime()` function can't access `exampleVariable`. Is there any workaround?

Here is whole code:

```
function convertTime(publishedDate){
    alert(publishedDate);
    var date = publishedDate;
    var publishedDay = date.toLocaleDateString();
    var publishedHour = date.getHours();            //nemozno pouzit toLocaleTimeString (cielovy format ma byt bez sekund)
    if (publishedHour < 10){
        publishedHour = "0" + publishedHour;
    };
    var publishedMinute = date.getMinutes();        //nacitanie hodin a minut
    if (publishedMinute < 10){
        publishedMinute = "0" + publishedMinute;
    };
    var publishedTime = publishedHour +":"+ publishedMinute;    //ich nasledne spojenie do casoveho formatu HH:MM
    var publishedDateConverted = publishedDay +", "+ publishedTime;
};
function loadZive(publishedDateConverted){
google.load("feeds", "1");  
    function initialize() {
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.zive.sk/rss/sc-47/default.aspx");
        feed.setNumEntries(window.localStorage.getItem("entriesNumber"));
        feed.load(function(result) {
            if (!result.error) {
                var feedlist = document.getElementById("feedZive");
                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                    var A = document.createElement("A");
                    var descriptionSettings = window.localStorage.getItem("descriptionSettings");
                    if (descriptionSettings=="true"){
                        var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
                        var p = document.createElement("p");
                        var pDate = document.createElement("p");
                        pDate.setAttribute("class","ui-li-aside");
                        var publishedDate = new Date(entry.publishedDate);
                        convertTime();
                        pDate.appendChild(document.createTextNode(publishedDateConverted));
                        h3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
                        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.content));
                        A.setAttribute("href",entry.link);
                        A.appendChild(h3);
                        A.appendChild(p);
                        A.appendChild(pDate);
                        }
                    else{
                        A.setAttribute("href",entry.link);
                        A.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
                    };
                    li.appendChild(A);
                    feedlist.appendChild(li);
                }
                $("#feedZive").listview("refresh");
            }
        });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);   
};
```

Alert result is Undefined.
**PS**: `exampleVariable` isn't defined by the user; it is loaded from a feed, so I cannot define it before the `convertTime()` function.

Comment: pass the exampleVariable as a parameter in convertTime() method as convertTime(exampleVariable) ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Danny said, or you can also pass variables this way:

```
function convertTime(exampleVariable){
    alert(exampleVariable);
};
function loadZive(){
    var exampleVariable = 3;
    convertTime(exampleVariable);
};
```

Comment: lets say that exampleVariable = new Date();. Can I also pass this as parameter? Because it looks like that this is not working and I am getting invalid date insinde convertTime();

Comment: @horin If you changed `var exampleVariable = 3;` to be `var exampleVariable = new Date()`: it should still work fine. There must be something else in your code that you did not provide here that is at fault.

Comment: You're calling `convertTime();` when you should be calling `convertTime(publishedDate);`

Comment: ok, now I am getting date inside convertTime(); function. Right now I need to pass publishedDateConverted to loadZive();. I have tried defining loadZive as function loadZive(publishedDateConverted); as you can see in my code. But it is not working. I have also tried putting it inside convertTime parameters but it still isnt working.

Comment: You want to pass the date from `loadZive()` to `convertTime()` and back again? That's an infinite loop. What I think you want to do is:

Change `loadZive()` back to looking like that. Change `convertTime(publishedDate);` to `publishedDateConverted = convertTime(publishedDate);` (in `loadZive()`) and then change `var publishedDateConverted = publishedDay +", "+ publishedTime;` to `return publishedDay +", "+ publishedTime;` (in `convertTime()`)

Comment: I want to pass publishedDate inside convertTime(). ConvertTime function will then covert the date to format that I want and the result is publishedDateConverted. And I want to pass publishedDateConverted from convertTime() back to loadZive() so I can post the converted format of date. I dont think thats an infinite loop. Imagine that converTime is just time converter which at entry has publishedDate from loadZive() and at output it has publishedDateConverted which should be passed back to loadZive()

Comment: The way you're trying to do it is an infinite loop, the way I just described is not. Make the changes I mentioned and you should get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var` from `loadZive()`, this makes the variable local to `loadZive()` only.

Alternatively, pass `exampleVariable` as a parameter to `convertTime()`.